# call datatable on button click

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have reached this so far,

my JSON is incompatible with the data table

Error msg,

> DataTables warning: table id=RegSrc - Requested unknown parameter
>   'Filenum' for row 0, column 1

Please help

```
 <table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th><b>File Number</b></th>
                                                <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
                                                <th><b>DOB</b></th>
                                                <th><b>Age</b></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

JS code

```
    var Table = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
    data: [],
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": '<i data-toggle class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-primary h5 m-none" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>'
        },
        { data: "Filenum" },
        { data: "FullName" },
        { data: "DOB" },
```

"columns": [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { data: "Filenum" },
            { data: "FullName" },
            { data: "DOB" },
             { data: "Age" }
        ],

```
    rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
    filter: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: false,
    processing: true,
    retrieve: true
})
```

Button click function

```
    $("#srcmdlfrmbtn").on("click", function (event) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.SrchTxt = $('#srctxt').val(),
    obj.FnameSrctxt = $('#fnamesrc').val(),
    obj.SnameSrctxt = $('#snamesrc').val(),
    obj.TnameSrctxt = $('#tnamesrc').val(),
    obj.LnameSrctxt = $('#lnamesrc').val(),
    obj.TelSrcTxt = $('#telsrc').val(),
    obj.SSNSrcTxt = $('#ssnsrc').val(),
    obj.EmailSrctxt = $('#emailsrc').val(),
    obj.DOBSrcTxt = $('#dobsrc').val()
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../CONFIG/WebSerTblsSearch.asmx/SrcTblReg",
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataFilter: function (res) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(res);
            var morp = JSON.parse(parsed.d);
            console.log(JSON.stringify( morp ))
            //return JSON.stringify({ data: morp });
            Table.clear().draw();
            Table.rows.add(JSON.stringify({ data: morp })).draw();
        },
    })

});
```

My JSON Array results

```
[{"Filenum":15090248,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170418115,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170418116,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170227111,"FullName":"asd dsf as a","DOB":"27 Feb 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":15112775,"FullName":"marwam saleh moh saleem","DOB":"26 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15112777,"FullName":"marwam saleh moh saleem","DOB":"26 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15120996,"FullName":"marwam mohmmad  saleem","DOB":null,"Age":null},{"Filenum":160215104,"FullName":"marwam mohmmad abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"12 Mar 2016","Age":1},{"Filenum":15112270,"FullName":"mohammad j saleh raqaad","DOB":"22 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15112772,"FullName":"salem mohmmad john sarjes","DOB":"22 Oct 2011","Age":6}]
```

Comment: Where is DOB in your json?

Comment: give a second please to correct the post

Comment: I corrected the table makeup and the final array,,, sorry for the confusion

Comment: is it the brackets that cause my issue?

Comment: now you are missing {data:"Age"}

Comment: its in my code, i forgot to correct it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
        Table.clear().draw();
        Table.rows.add(JSON.stringify({ data: morp })).draw();
```

to

```
  Table.clear().draw();
  Table.rows.add( morp ).draw();
```

and it started working

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains two column in each row and your dataTable trying to populate four column in each row, so as per your JSON request your dataTable will be as Below  .

```
 <table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>File Number</b></th>
            <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var Table = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
    data: [],
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": '<i data-toggle class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-primary h5 m-none" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>'
        },
        { data: "Filenum" },
        { data: "FullName" },
    ],

    rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
    filter: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: false,
    processing: true,
    retrieve: true
})
```